# Showing that we can write $E_{\lambda}=I-E^{+}_{\lambda}$.

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, unbounded-operators

Let $A:\mathscr{D}(A)\subset\mathscr{H}\to\mathscr{H}$ be an unbounded self-adjoint operator and $(E_{\lambda})_{\lambda\in\mathbb{R}}$ its spectral family and $E_{\lambda}=E((-\infty,\lambda])$, with $E$ the resolution of the identity on $\mathbb{R}$.

I'm trying to show that one can write $E_{\lambda}=I-E^{+}_{\lambda}$, whereby $E^{+}_{\lambda}$ is the orthogonal projection on $\mathscr{N}((A-\lambda)-|A-\lambda|)$.

Thus far I have followed a hint which suggests to express $(A-\lambda)-|A-\lambda|$ as an integral using the spectral theorem. Namely for fixed $\eta\in\mathbb{R}$ and we can define the function
     $$f(\eta)=(\eta-\lambda)-|\eta-\lambda|,$$
    so that by the spectral theorem:
    $$ \begin{aligned}\langle f(A)x,x\rangle&=\langle ((A-\lambda)-|A-\lambda|)x,x\rangle\\&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\eta)\,d\langle E_{\eta}x,x\rangle\\&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(\eta)\,dF_{x}(\eta)=\langle\Psi(f)x,x\rangle,\end{aligned} $$
where $F_{x}(\eta)$ is the generalised function defined by
    $$ F_{x}(\eta):=\int_{-\infty}^{\eta}\,d\langle E_{\eta}x,x\rangle. $$

However, I really don't know where to go from this hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f_{\lambda}(\eta)=(\eta-\lambda)-|\eta-\lambda|$ is $0$ for $\eta \le \lambda$ and is $2(\eta-\lambda)$ for $\eta < \lambda$. Therefore,
$$
      (A-\lambda I)x-|A-\lambda I|x=\int_{-\infty}^{\lambda}2(\eta-\lambda)dE(\eta)x, \\
         \|(A-\lambda I)x-|A-\lambda I|x\|^2=4\int_{-\infty}^{\lambda}|\eta-\lambda|^2d\|E(\eta)x\|^2
$$
It follows that $x\in\mathcal{N}((A-\lambda I)-|A-\lambda I|)$ iff
$$
                          \|E(-\infty,\lambda)x\|=0.
$$
(The open interval on the right is important.) And $E(-\infty,\lambda)=I-E[\lambda,\infty)$.

Comment: My calculations were slightly different to yours; namely: $$\begin{aligned}
 \langle ((A-\lambda I)-|A-\lambda I|)x,x\rangle&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{\lambda}(\eta)d\langle E_{\eta}x,x\rangle
 \\
 &=2\int_{-\infty}^{\lambda}(\eta-\lambda)d\langle E_{\eta}x,x\rangle
 \\
 &=2\int_{-\infty}^{\lambda}(\eta-\lambda)d\mu_{\|E_{\eta}x\|^{2}}.
 \end{aligned}$$
However, the result is the same in that $x\in\mathscr{N}((A-\lambda I-|A-\lambda I|)\iff\|E_{\eta}x\|=\|E(-\infty,\lambda)x\|=0$. Also, which "open interval" are you referring to and I still don't see how the final result follows?

Comment: Oh, okay; I think it's simply $E_{\lambda}=E(-\infty,\lambda]=I-E(\lambda,\infty)=I-E^{+}_{\lambda}$.